# Printing out an Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am relatively new to php. What I am trying to do is replicate a page where you can order pizza. However, I'm having trouble printing an output from a multi select menu. When I execute the PHP, it only says "array", instead of all the choices selected. I want it to say all the choices. Here is the HTML:

```
<p>Select which cheese you want on your pizza:</p>
<select  size="4" name="Cheese[]" multiple required> 
<option value="Mozzarella">Mozzarella</option>
<option value="Parmesan">Parmesan</option>
<option value="Gouda">Gouda</option>
<option value="Provolone"> Provolone</option>
</select>
```

And here is my PHP that I submit my form to:

```
<tr>

<? foreach ($submitted_form_data as $key=>$value) { ?>

<td><?=$value?> </td>

<? } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

My goal is to be able to have all the selected items printed out onto one row. For the ones that have multiple choices, I want them to be also listed.
The output would show like:

pizza mushroom cheddar John Smith Smith@email.com Address

Comment: Can you send whole code? Including <form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can always start off by seeing what's in the array by doing

```
print_r($array_name);
```

Once you've got that it'll help you understand what the output is.

You don't need the key because we already know its cheese so getting the output with POST and then using the code below will do it no problem.

```
foreach ($array as $cheese) {
   echo $cheese;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to keep the HTML within the PHP code here for readability:

```
<tr>
<?php 
foreach ($submitted_form_data as $val) {
    echo "<td>",$val,"</td>",PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</tr>
```

If you are curious about the content of your array, use:

```
var_dump($submitted_form_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['Cheese'] is an array, depending on how many cheeses you select, you will need to access them by $_POST['Cheese'][0], $_POST['Cheese'][1] etc.

consider this:

```
    <p>Select which cheese you want on your pizza:</p>
    <form name="pizza" method="post">
        <select  size="4" name="Cheese[]" multiple required> 
            <option value="Mozzarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="Parmesan">Parmesan</option>
            <option value="Gouda">Gouda</option>
            <option value="Provolone"> Provolone</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="oh boy!" />
    </form>

    <?php
    if( isset( $_POST ) ) {
        echo 'I want ' . implode( ', ',$_POST['Cheese'] ) , ' on my pizza!';
    }
    ?>
```